# String replace logic

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a function, that receives a string with this format:

"hello wor**"

The * could be anywhere on the string.

It should return:

```
<span>hello wor</span><input type='text'></input>
```

So the string could be "hel** wor*d" also

and the return should be:

```
<span>hel</span><input type='text'> <span>wor</span><input type='text'><span>d</span>
```

I could do it easily with a loop on each char, but I'm looking for more elegant solutions.

I think that it could be solved with a regex, and using replace I got the "*" covered:

```
var text = "hello wor**";
text.replace(/\*+/g, "<input type='text'></input>");
```

I have not yet found a way of capturing the remaining text to render the

```
<span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, that would work for the example string, but not for "hel** world" for example.  The * could be anywhere on the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the result of the `replace` function. Try this:

```js
var text = "*hel** wor*d*";
var element = text.split(/\s*\*+\s*/g);
element = "<span>"+ element.join("</span><input type='text'><span>") + "</span>";
element = element.replace(/<span><\/span>/g, "");

console.log(element);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've edited the question to clarify some points.

Comment: @AlexTakitani this answer is just missing a "<span>" at the second replace param and a +"</span>" at the end to work

Comment: @AlexTakitani Sorry, you are right. Now it should work :)

Comment: Thank you @IlarioPierbattista very clever solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
'hello wor**'.replace(/\*+/g, "<input type='text'></input>");
```

This returns `hello wor`. All you have to do is concatenate the string with the rest of the data you want, like so:

```
var text = "hello wor**";
text = '<span>' + text.replace(/\*+/g, '') + '</span><input type=\'text\'></input>';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've edited the question to clarify some points.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="hi">hello wor**</span> 
  </body>
</html>
```

i use jquery in this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var texty = $('#hi').text();

        $('#hi').replaceWith(texty.replace(/\*+/g, "<input type='text'></input>"))
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've edited the question to clarify some points.